# How to get this colour in pine?

Tags: wood, paint, varnish, pine, painting

any idea how this color can be achieved?
Both the body and top, which seems to be different

On top I believe is some sort of black wenge diluted, but the other one im not sure if it is grey and wiped with a cloth or something,

[image]

[image]

[image]

Im thinking on using water based varnish btw

Thanks

Comment: For the main body of the desk, just let the board sit outside for 6-12 months, then sand lightly in some random spots along the edges.

Comment: Thats a lot of time :)

Comment: You asked for "any" ideas, not time efficient ones...

Comment: Ideally we need more info than you've provided to be able to provide a good Answer (e.g. so that recommendations are based on what's available in your market) but really you're going to have to do some experimentation anyway because your wood may not stain quite like someone else's. The main body looks like it could simply be pressure-treated softwood with semi-random sanding o_O Not that it's relevant but this looks godawful to my eyes, sooo much better than this is possible and to that end I think the dark top should probably be approached using "gel stain". [contd]

Comment: The tops don't look like they were coloured with that but it's what I'd recommend you use anyway as it'll give you a *better* result than in the photos. So-called gel stain is thickened coloured varnish, not stain in the conventional sense, so it colours pine much more evenly that true stains tend to — preventing the 'grain reversal' you can see in some of the above images. Note however that "gel stains" are an oil-based product so you'll need to be careful if you intend to use a waterbased final varnish on this part also.

Comment: Search Youtube for "how to get a barn wood effect on new lumber"  or anything about  fake Aging or  fake old wood techniques.

Answer (score 2):

To me it looks like it is “grey washed”

Instructions can be found here for example: https://www.wikihow.com/Grey-Wash-Wood

And maybe I’m stating the obvious, but remember to first experiment on a few scrap pieces of wood before applying it to your furniture